# Restrict Keyword and Pointers inside structs

Tags: c, function, struct, restrict-qualifier

By using the `restrict` keyword like this:

```
int f(int* restrict a, int* restrict b);
```

I can instruct the compiler that arrays a and b do not overlap. Say I have a structure:

```
struct s{
(...)
int* ip;
};
```

and write a function that takes two `struct s` objects:

```
int f2(struct s a, struct s b);
```

How can I similarly instruct the compiler in this case that `a.ip` and `b.ip` do not overlap?

Answer (score 17):

You can also use `restrict` inside a structure.

```
struct s {
    /* ... */
    int * restrict ip;
};

int f2(struct s a, struct s b)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Thus a compiler can assume that `a.ip` and `b.ip` are used to refer to disjoint object for the duration of each invocation of the `f2` function.

Answer (score -2):

Check this **pointer** example , You might get some help.

```
// xa and xb pointers cannot overlap ie. point to same memmpry location.
void function (restrict int *xa, restrict int *xb)
{
    int temp = *xa;
    *xa = *xb;
    xb = temp;
}
```

If two pointers are declared as restrict then these two pointers doesnot overlap.

**EDITED**

[Check this link for more examples](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13825)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question - OP clearly knows how to do it with plain pointers, the code's in the question.

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good solution to write a function that works with the types of a.ip and b.ip rather than a and b. That depends on the nature of the struct, if a and b are incomplete types uses in a OO design, then that method wouldn't work.